# Cordova 5.3.3 - ANDROID_HOME not found

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, gradle, sdk

I'm working in a cordova App, but I need use cordova version 5.3.3, because we dont have permission for update him. Then, I have big problems to run this app, this error apear for me when a run the comand **"cordova run android"**. The image is below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3wUs.png)

Comment: @Tiaga you are able to add android platform without any issues?

Comment: usually inside android project there is a file called local.properties. and inside this file you will specify the android sdk path. sdk.dir=<your android sdk path>

Comment: I found the solution. In the new update at the Android Studio and SDK, the templates/gradle folder only stay in the android studio folder, but Cordova 5.0.0 search this folder (templates/gradle) in sdk folder. I needed copy and paste the folder templates/gradle that was in android studio folder to sdk folder. Thank you so much.